# SQL Server : sort record special

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, select, sql-order-by

SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Kengen
```

The result:

```
A
B
C
D
S
```

But I want to result are:

```
S
A
B
C
D
```

How to order by like this?

Comment: Can you give some more detail on why you'd want this sort? For example, what would happen if you had 'T' or 'P' rows? Or 'F' ?

Comment: Result are: S A B C D E F ....

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `case` expression to create a custom sorting that will put the `'S'` first:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     kengen
ORDER BY CASE col WHEN 'S' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, col
```

Comment: @Ken please mark as the answer if you're happy with it.